# Resolving problems with backup?

Tags: settings, backup

For about 2 months now, it appears that backup has been failing to backup correctly - If I kick off a manual backup, the progress works up to 98%, and then fails with a message "There was a problem backing up your settings. Try again later.":

[image: There was a problem backing up your settings. Try again later.]

Is there something I can do to resolve this, that won't cause me to lose my settings? I have been trying from a solid WiFi connection, so I don't believe it to be a temporary issue.

Comment: I was experiencing the same problem on an ATT Lumia 1520. Deleting the existing backup (on the manage backup page) and manually starting a new back up works. (note: it takes much longer than normal to do that manual backup)

Comment: Tried this on my Lumia 735 after receiving backup errors. Tried the back-up again......
Got to 96%...then 100% - worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try deleting all your current backups and do a new, completely fresh one.

Comment: Yeah, this should possibly fix the issue.

Comment: I can confirm this fixes the problem.

Comment: Didn't work for me... anyone know where the backup lives on OneDrive?

Comment: Backups won't be stored as files that you can look at in your OneDrive folder. Instead you can see all your device backups on this page https://onedrive.live.com/Options/DeviceBackups

Comment: This method worked for my Lumia 925 as well.